# Create a simple array in liquid

Tags: php, shopify, liquid

I need to make an associative array of products by their quantity. How do I convert this one liner from php to liquid

```
foreach(items as item) $product[$item.product_id] += $item.quantity
```

Best I came up was with this

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% assign product[item.product_id] = 0 | plus product[item.product_id] | plus item.quantity %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve here? Since the current code doesn't have any logic behind it (in Shopify terms), it's not just wrong it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @drip I think reading the code, you can understand what I am doing. It is self explanatory. But I have added it in question if you still did not get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create arrays in the same way as other languages in liquid. The only way to create an array is after you split a string.

So you can't create an array item using `product[item.product_id]`.

You first need to generate a String and then create the array by splitting that string.

```
{%- capture items -%}
    {%- for line_item in cart.items -%}
        {{- line_item.product_id -}}|{{-line_item.quantity-}},
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}

{% assign items_array = items | split: ',' %}
```

That's why we capture the output and split it in order to create the array.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Liquid is such a mess